# How to prevent UIImageView from resizing with Autolayout

Tags: ios, ios6, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm recreating my UI with auto layout and have a navbar across the top and a 2x2 grid of UIImageViews filling the rest of the screen. I put in all the constraints so it maintains this arrangement in any orientation and it's working well when the UIImageViews don't have an image in them. When I programmatically load an image in the UIImageViews, they change size and placement even though I have constraints that should prevent this.

I have all the autoresizing masks off for everything and the UIImageViews set to Aspect fit.

This autolayout stuff is new to me, but I thought I had it working...until I put an image in there. Why would that change the size and placement of the UIImageViews?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make sure each of your UIImageViews has height and width constraints

Comment: If I hard code a width and height constraint, won't that override the autolayout when it switches orientation? I thought that constraints were to help avoiding hardcoded width & height values...

Comment: No...It's to avoid hardcoding the frame since the frame now changes as your container size change. However if the behavior you want is for your frame's size to not change...then that's what you do, but the frame's origin values can still depend on the container

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. If I hardcode a width or height, I get errors saying that it had to break a constraint and when I rotate the device the width and height are incorrect and should have changed.

Comment: Constraints are just rules to follow when the container size changes. If you have a trailing and leading to superview constraint AND a width, then the 3 should add up to the width of the superview. If they don't you get an error. So you need to change your leading and trailing constraints to do what you want them to do. If you just want leading to remain constant, you can remove your trailing constraint. Or you can use the less than or greater than relation.

Comment: I've tried to duplicate you condition, but can't -- my image views don't change size or position when adding images. Did you add the constraints in code, or do it in IB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify contraints at runtime if you link them with an outlet in your view controller.

For your case you would add a width and height constraint and link them to two outlets.
Then after you know the image dimensions you would change the constant value.

I am describing this in detail for a similar use case I had here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/first-good-auto-layout-use-case/

Comment: This was a big help, thanks. I'm glad I'm not the only one having a crazy time with constraints. While I love the reasoning behind the whole thing, the implementation leaves a lot to be desired. Thanks again.