# AutoLayout Difficulties

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am trying to layout a pretty simple screen. I have cleared out all warnings and errors and everything looks great on the storyboard. But when the screen draws, my `UIImageView` gets compressed vertically. I can't figure this out. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or suggest what I should be looking at? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Notice how the image is vertically compressed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you didn't specify height constraint of the imageView.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998203/how-to-prevent-uiimageview-from-resizing-with-autolayout if you need to dynamically set the width/height constraint.